# Change page layout for multiple pages

Tags: publishing-site, page-layout, publishing-page

Is there a quick way to change the page layout of many pages (à la datasheet view, or in SPD maybe)?

Editing and republishing each one individually seems rather onerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this wouldn't be possible in the SharePoint UI or SharePoint Designer.  The only way to do this would be through custom code (i.e. C# code in a Visual Studio solution).

Comment: It's really difficult for me to feign surprise for these kinds of absurdities anymore. Thanks for the answer, I guess it's hundreds of page loads for me then.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint ;-) Most people have a love/hate relationship with it.